# Is it safe to create a petproject based on a Pokemon franchise?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, internet

Long story short, i'm a web developer and i want to create a petproject.
Let say, it will be named "Pokemon Battle Assistant" and it will be about Pokemon. I want to implement a website, an Android app and an app for voice assistant. All of it non-commercial, mostly for fun, but all public.

What kind of legal problems i might expect from The Pokémon Company and Nintendo company? And what i can do to mitigate them?

Comment: What does this project do, specifically?

Comment: Pokémon is trademarked. Also...

Comment: Pokemon database (to lookup data about Pokemons), comparison (compare two or more Pokemons), battle assistant (for example, user asks "Who do i battle Pikachu Lvl37?" or "Where can i get an Eevie?" and getting a response from assistant).

Comment: And I additionally emphasize: no commercial usage of a trademark, no paid apps, no monetization, nothing. Might i still have some problems if i just put word Pokemon (or use names of actual Pokemons (which is also subject to trademark) in my app?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your app would be something similar to the [Pokémon Showdown Damage Calculator](https://calc.pokemonshowdown.com/)? Then probable, the same answer [given here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228641/what-is-the-legality-of-pokemon-showdown) would apply; your app is infringing, Nintendo/The Pokémon Company can shut it down whenever, but they might choose not to if you're lucky.

Comment: Nintendo/Pokemon Company are known to be highly litigious too